# EWS TimeZone not found error - localization issue?

Tags: localization, timezone, exchangewebservices

We have the following situation with a client when synchronizing Exchange calendar with EWS:

On the Win 10 client computer, calling GetTimeZoneInformation returns `TIME_ZONE_ID_DAYLIGHT`, i.e. 'The system is operating in the range covered by the DaylightDate member of the TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION structure.'
The StandardName is: W. Europe Standard Time
The DaylightName is: W. Europe Daylight Time

IIRC correctly, I now need to search through the `Dlt` entries of `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\` to determine the root key name for the time zone.
But 'W. Europe Daylight Time' is not present: There are 139 entries but none of them has a `Dlt` entry named 'W. Europe Daylight Time'

So my code can't convert to the proper root key name and puts 'W. Europe Daylight Time' in EWS SOAP calls like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:typ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
  xmlns:mes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
<soapenv:Header>
  <typ:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013"/>
  <typ:MailboxCulture>en-US</typ:MailboxCulture>
  <typ:TimeZoneContext>
     <typ:TimeZoneDefinition Id="W. Europe Daylight Time"/>
  </typ:TimeZoneContext>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
  <mes:ResolveNames ReturnFullContactData="1" SearchScope="ActiveDirectory">
    <mes:UnresolvedEntry>someone@somewhere.com</mes:UnresolvedEntry>
  </mes:ResolveNames>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

... and these fail with errors like:

```
GetCalendarFolder (calendar): FaultInBody: A time zone with the specified ID could not be found.
Details: ErrorTimeZone Id: W. Europe Daylight Time
```

On the client machine, searching the registry for 'W. Europe', I find *one* entry that says:

```
RootKeyName: W. Europe Standard Time
  DisplayName: (UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlijn, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Wenen
  StandardName: West-Europa (standaardtijd)
  DaylightName: West-Europa (zomertijd)
```

This machine has the following language settings:

```
Default system UI language : en-US
System locale : nl-NL
Default time zone : W. Europe Standard Time
Installed language(s): en-US
  Type : Fully localized language.
Installed language(s): nl-NL
  Type : Partially localized language, MUI type.
  Fallback Languages en-US
```

My suspicion is that these 'localized'(?) StandardName/DaylightName registry values prevent me from properly looking up the 'W. Europe Standard Time' time zone ID.

FWIW, the Exchange server has:

```
TIME_ZONE_ID_DAYLIGHT
StandardName: W. Europe Standard Time
DaylightName: W. Europe Daylight Time
```

and *does* have a registry entry

```
RootKeyName: W. Europe Standard Time
  DisplayName: (UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna
  StandardName: W. Europe Standard Time
  DaylightName: W. Europe Daylight Time
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two separate concepts mixed together.

- The `ID` of the time zone is `"W. Europe Standard Time"`.  It isn't localized for other languages, and it does not change for daylight saving time.  The same string is used to cover both standard time and daylight time, despite the word *Standard* being in it. (This is a common source of confusion, and is also covered in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).)
- The `StandardName`, `DaylightName`, and `DisplayName` are localized by the OS language, and are not identifiers.  They are meant for human display only.  For example, the `DisplayName` is generally paired with the ID in drop-down lists to pick a time zone.  The display name would be shown to the user, and the corresponding ID would be saved in the application.  The `StandardName` and `DaylightName` are used for human display in conjunction with a specific date and time, depending on which is in effect.

That `GetTimeZoneInformation` returns `TIME_ZONE_ID_DAYLIGHT` is irrelevant.  You should not be using it to mutate the name of the ID (i.e., don't replace "standard" with "daylight").

Ultimately it sounds like you just need the user's time zone id. There are lots of ways to get that.  Any of the following would work:

- Using the Win32 API, you can call [`GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-getdynamictimezoneinformation), which returns a [`DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/ns-timezoneapi-dynamic_time_zone_information) structure.  The `TimeZoneKeyName` is the ID you should use.
- You can get this directly from the registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation` in the `TimeZoneKeyName` value
- If you are writing .NET code, you can get it from `TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id`
- From the command line, you can call `tzutil /g`

Comment: GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation did the trick. Makes the code a lot easier ;-)